# Is it good to query the user object in mongo on every page?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, session

So I'm creating a web application currently where a user can log in. I wondered what's the best practice for storing user information. Should I store the user object in the current session, so I don't have to keep querying the user's database? Or should I store the user Id and query it every time the user goes to a new webpage? Storing the User's id and querying it every time will get the most up-to-date information but I'm not sure how this will affect the performance, especially if I decide to scale this app and have thousands of users.